# Python CSV not writing data to file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am running into a wall with this.  I am new to writing CSV files with python and have been reading lots of different posts on the topic, but now I ran into a wall with this and could use a little help.

```
import csv
#headers from the read.csv file that I wan't to parse and write to the new file.
headers = ['header1', 'header5', 'header6', 'header7']
#open the write.csv file to write the data to
with open("write.csv", 'wb') as csvWriter:
    writer = csv.writer(csvWriter)
#open the main data file that I want to parse data out of and write to write.csv
with open('reading.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',' )
    csvList = list(readCSV)
    #finds where the position of the data I want to pull out and write to write.csv
    itemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[0])
    vendorName = csvList[0].index(headers[1])
    supplierID = csvList[0].index(headers[2])
    supplierItemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[3])
    for row in readCSV:
        writer.writerow([row[itemCode], row[vendorName], row[supplierID], row[supplierItemCode]])
    csvWriter.close()
```

---UPDATE---
I made the changes suggested and tried commenting out the following part of the code & changing 'wb' to 'w' and the program worked.  However, I don't understand why, and how do I set this up so that I can list the header I want to pull out?

```
csvList = list(readCSV)
itemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[0])
vendorName = csvList[0].index(headers[1])
supplierID = csvList[0].index(headers[2])
supplierItemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[3])
```

Here is my updated code:

```
 headers = ['header1', 'header5', 'header6', 'header7']
    #open the write.csv file to write the data to
    with open("write.csv", 'wb') as csvWriter, open('reading.csv') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvWriter)
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',' )
        """csvList = list(readCSV)
        #finds where the position of the data I want to pull out and write to write.csv
        itemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[0])
        vendorName = csvList[0].index(headers[1])
        supplierID = csvList[0].index(headers[2])
        supplierItemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[3])"""
        for row in readCSV:
            writer.writerow([row[0], row[27], row[28], row[29]])
```

Comment: writer  can not be accessed in writer.writerow([row[itemCode], row[vendorName], row[supplierID], row[supplierItemCode]]),this shoud throw an errow actually

Comment: can you post the error you re getting as edit of below the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to write a subset of columns to a new file.  This problem is simpler with `DictReader`/`DictWriter`.  Note the correct use of `open` when using Python 3.x.  Your attempt was using the Python 2.x way.

```
import csv

# headers you want in the order you want
headers = ['header1','header5','header6','header7']

with open('write.csv','w',newline='') as csvWriter,open('read.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvWriter,fieldnames=headers,extrasaction='ignore')
    readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in readCSV:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Test data:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
11,22,33,44,55,66,77
```

Output:

```
header1,header5,header6,header7
1,5,6,7
11,55,66,77
```

Comment: thanks for showing me this! It totally fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to access both writer under the same block,you should do something like this

```
with open("write.csv", 'wb') as csvWriter,open('reading.csv') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvWriter)
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',' )
    csvList = list(readCSV)
    #finds where the position of the data I want to pull out and write to write.csv
    itemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[0])
    vendorName = csvList[0].index(headers[1])
    supplierID = csvList[0].index(headers[2])
    supplierItemCode = csvList[0].index(headers[3])
    for row in readCSV:
        writer.writerow([row[itemCode], row[vendorName], row[supplierID], row[supplierItemCode]])
    csvWriter.close()
```

Comment: @Bokai did it fix your problem?

Comment: that change didn't fix the program.  However, it is very useful.  I updated the main post with the code updates.

Answer (score 0):

The `with open() as csvWriter:` construct handles closing of the supplied file once you exit the block. So once you get down to `writer.writerow`, the file is already closed.

You need to enclose the entire expression in the `with open` block.

```
with open("write.csv", 'wb') as csvWriter:
    ....
    #Do all writing within this block
    ....
```